# Getting IndexError: list index out of range in python

Tags: python

I am running a python program from github and getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 181, in <module>
    main(num)
  File "create.py", line 100, in main
    link2 = link2.split('https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me as to why?  I can provide source code if needed.

The program seems to run ok for a while and then errors out, but this can happen sometimes after creating one account, other times it creates 30 before it happens.  Not sure what's going on, was hoping someone here would possibly be able to help.

```
#https://github.com/TCWTEAM
#Made by XO
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
from utils import c_logging, n_logging
import string
import names
from time import sleep
from random import *
import os
import sys

os.remove("accounts.txt")
f = open("accounts.txt", "w+")
f.close()

with open('config.json') as file:
config = json.load(file)
    file.close()

def dot_trick(username):
    emails = list()
    username_length = len(username)
    combinations = pow(2, username_length - 1)
    padding = "{0:0" + str(username_length - 1) + "b}"
    for i in range(0, combinations):
        bin = padding.format(i)
        full_email = ""
        for j in range(0, username_length - 1):
            full_email += (username[j]);
            if bin[j] == "1":
                full_email += "."
        full_email += (username[j + 1])
        emails.append(full_email + "@gmail.com")
    return emails

def main(num):
    count = 0
    headers = {
           'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host':'www.adidas.com',
    'Origin':'https://www.adidas.com',
    'Referer':'https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36'
}

for i in range(int(num)):
    min_char = 9
    max_char = 14
    min_char0 = 8
    max_char0 = 10
    allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    rprefix = "".join(choice(allchar) for x in range(randint(min_char0, max_char0)))
    passw = config['password']
    s = requests.session()

    a = s.post("https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/", headers=headers)
    soup0 = bs(a.content, "html.parser")
    sk1 = soup0.find('input', {'name':'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_securekey'})
    sk1 = str(sk1)
    sk1 = sk1.split('value="')[1]
    sk1 = sk1.split('"/>')[0]

    link0 = soup0.find_all('form', {'data-component':'form/Form'})
    link0 = str(link0)
    link0 = link0.split('https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/')[1]
    link0 = link0.split('" class="fanyform"')[0]
    link0 = link0.split('"')[0]
    link0 = "https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/{}".format(link0)

    firstname = names.get_first_name(gender='male')
    lastname = names.get_last_name()

    dayofmonth = randint(1, 25)
    month = randint(1, 12)
    year = randint(1990, 1999)

    payload1 = {
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_firstname':firstname,
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_lastname':lastname,
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_customer_birthday_dayofmonth':dayofmonth,
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_customer_birthday_month':month,
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_customer_birthday_year':year,
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_step1':'Next',
        'dwfrm_mipersonalinfo_securekey':sk1,
    }

    req1 = s.post(link0, data=payload1, headers=headers)

    soup1 = bs(req1.content, "html.parser")
    link2 = soup1.find_all('form', {'id':'dwfrm_milogininfo'})
    link2 = str(link2)
    link2 = link2.split('https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/')[1]
    link2 = link2.split('" class="fanyform"')[0]
    link2 = link2.split('"')[0]
    link2 = "https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/{}".format(link2)

    sk2 = soup1.find('input', {'name':'dwfrm_milogininfo_securekey'})
    sk2 = str(sk2)
    sk2 = sk2.split('value="')[1]
    sk2 = sk2.split('"/>')[0]

    emailJig = config['emailJig']
    emailJig = emailJig.upper()

    if emailJig == "GMAIL":
        prefix = config['email'].split("@")[0]
        dotarray = dot_trick(prefix)
        dotnum = randint(0, len(dotarray) - 1)
        email = dotarray[dotnum]
    else:
        prefix = config['email'].split("@")[0]
        domain = config['email'].split("@")[1]
        email = "{}{}@{}".format(prefix, rprefix, domain)


    payload2 = {
        'dwfrm_milogininfo_email':email,
        'dwfrm_milogininfo_password':passw,
        'dwfrm_milogininfo_newpasswordconfirm':passw,
        'dwfrm_milogininfo_step2':'Next',
        'dwfrm_milogininfo_securekey':sk2,
    }

    req2 = s.post(link2, data=payload2, headers=headers)

    soupf = bs(req2.content, "html.parser")
    link3 = soupf.find_all('form', {'id':'dwfrm_micommunicinfo'})
    link3 = str(link3)
    link3 = link3.split('https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/')[1]
    link3 = link3.split('" class="fanyform"')[0]
    link3 = link3.split('"')[0]
    link3 = "https://www.adidas.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-US-Site/en_US/MiAccount-Register/{}".format(link3)

    sk3 = soupf.find('input', {'name':'dwfrm_micommunicinfo_securekey'})
    sk3 = str(sk3)
    sk3 = sk3.split('value="')[1]
    sk3 = sk3.split('"/>')[0]

    payload3 = {
        'dwfrm_micommunicinfo_agreeterms':'true',
        'dwfrm_micommunicinfo_step3':'Register',
        'dwfrm_micommunicinfo_securekey':sk3,
    }

    req3 = s.post(link3, data=payload3, headers=headers)
    if req3.status_code == 200:
        count = count + 1
        f = open("accounts.txt", "a+")
        f.write("{}:{} | {} {}\n".format(email, passw, firstname, lastname))
        c_logging("Created Account {}/{}".format(count, num), "green")
    else:
        c_logging("Error Creating Account", "red")
c_logging("Created {}/{} Accounts".format(count, num), "magenta")
c_logging("If you love me paypal.me/ehxoh", "magenta")




if __name__ == '__main__':
n_logging("===========================")
c_logging("Adidas Account Creator 1", "cyan")
c_logging("Made By JG", "cyan")
c_logging("paypal.me/jackgordonGB", "cyan")
n_logging("===========================")
print("")
n_logging("----------------------------")
c_logging("Email Jig: {}".format(config['emailJig']), "magenta")
c_logging("Email: {}".format(config['email']), "magenta")
c_logging("Password: {}".format(config['password']), "magenta")
n_logging("----------------------------")
print("")
num = input("# Of Accs To Create: ")
main(num)
```

Comment: By default `split` is on whitespace, which your string has none of, therefore the result will be a list with only a single element `[0]` which is the entire original string, What character did you want to split on? As a side note, breaking up urls is a much better job for [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) than `str.split`

Comment: `link2` doesn't contain the string you're splitting on (that Adidas URL), so the entirety of `link2` is in element 0 of the resulting list, and there is no element 1.

Comment: First of all, why are you passing an entire weblink in as a delimiter...

Comment: What exactly are you *trying to achieve* by splitting the URL? The error is explained by @CorKramer, but if you can explain desired output we can help a little more.

Comment: The problem isn't that there's no whitespace in the URL. A delimiter is being used here. The problem is that `link2` doesn't contain the delimiter.

Comment: so i'm not the one who wrote the program... i'm just trying to run it to generate some accounts.  perhaps if i post the python code it will help so i'll attach it.. ok put the code in!  Thanks for any help

Comment: The author has instructions on his GitHub. Don't waste other peoples time trying to get more pairs of Yeezy shoes. It is likely user error. Trouble shoot using his documentation.

Comment: i'm not asking how to run the program, it works but sometimes when running i get an error... there was nothing about it in the documentation which is why i asked if maybe someone here might know why... don't know why you get so angry about it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the weblink you are passing in as the delimiter, is not found in your "link2" object. I think you might not understand the split method entirely. The first argument the split method takes is a delimiter value. This is the value it looks to split the string on.

**Example**

```
a = 'Hello:World'
print(a.split(':'))

--> ['Hello', 'World']
```

Where `a` is the string object the split method is being called on, and `:` is the delimiter.

Now I am not exactly sure what your goal is, but if you were actually trying to pull that entire weblink out of a string, `split` is not a very good way to go about it. Try something like a regular expression.

**Something like this:**

```
import re

pattern = r'(https:\/\/www.adidas.com\/on\/demandware.store\/Sites-adidas-US-Site\/en_US\/MiAccount-Register\/)'
link2 = 'long string of links I can only guess'

print(re.findall(pattern, link2))  # --> returns list of strings matching pattern
```